# How to prove $2^n = \omega (n^k)$

Tags: notation

I'm trying to prove $2^n = \omega (n^k)$ but the problem is that, I could not find any examples of proving little/ small omega, and what makes it confusing is that I could not even find a way to deal with $k$.

I tried this: 
$$2^n > c (n^k).$$

If I take the logarithm of both sides, I get 
$$n > c (\log(n))^k = n > ck\log(n),$$
but then I'm lost!

I could solve it if it were Big-$O$ but for both big-$\Omega$ and small-$\omega$ I feel as I know nothing about math :(

I do not expect the answer as much as I expect a hand to lead me at least understand what going when it comes to Omega.

Comment: You can choose $c=k^2+1$.

Comment: Thank you, but what the next stop after that? I'm totally lost and could not make ant forward step after choosing c = K^2 + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
2^n >& cn^k\\
n \log 2 >& \log c + k \log n\\
n \log 2 - k\log n >& \log c
\end{align}$$

Now, since the left hand side function of $n$ has a derivative of $\frac{n\log 2-k}{n}$, for $n>\frac{k}{\log2}$ the function is increasing. And since the function will grow unbounded (limit at infinity is infinity), this function will be greater than any constant $\log c$ either for large $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much, very clear

Comment: Can we say for n > k ? as log2 = 1 !